# XML - Remove child from node with specific child

Tags: c#, xml

In the XML below, I'm trying to remove the nodes ADS and SCV from ONLY the PMT node that has an ID node with a value of AW.

```
<PCTX>
    <PMT>
        <ID>AW</ID>
        <CCS>NONE</CCS>
        <ADS>false</ADS> <!-- Remove this node only -->
        <SCV>None</SCV>  <!-- Remove this node only -->
        <PPIIMI>123</PPIIMI>
        <VER>10</VER>
        <INI>web</INI>
    </PMT>
    <PMT>
        <ID>AX</ID>
        <CCS>NONE</CCS>
        <ADS>false</ADS> <!-- Leave this node -->
        <SCV>MAN</SCV>   <!-- Leave this node -->
    </PMT>
</PCTX>
```

How would I do that?

Here is C# code trying to get it to work but getting nothing returned in pMethods. The PMT node with ID=AW will always be the first node in PCTX.

```
foreach (XmlNode pMethods in xmlObj.SelectNodes("/PCTX/PMT[1]"))
{
    {
        if (node.Name == "ADS" || node.Name == "SCV")
            pMethods.RemoveChild(node);
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed the index to 1, got the correct node but the loop to remove ends after the first removal.

Comment: Right, I'd suggest doing that with LINQ to XML. I would expect it to be relatively easy to find the ID element with value AW, take its parent, and remove the child ADS and SCV elements. Do you have code that doesn't work how you expect it to at the moment?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your c# code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Comment: XPath indexing starts at 1, you'll want to use an expression like `"/PCTX/PMT[1]/*"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I changed the indexer to 1 but the loop for removal only removes one of the 2 that I need to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> IdAw = doc.Descendants("PMT").Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == "AW").ToList();
            foreach(XElement pmt in IdAw)
            {
                pmt.Element("ADS").Remove();
                pmt.Element("SCV").Remove();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JonSkeet pointed out, it is better to use LINQ to XML.

One single LINQ to XML statement, no loops, does the job.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<PCTX>
        <PMT>
            <ID>AW</ID>
            <CCS>NONE</CCS>
            <ADS>false</ADS>
            <SCV>None</SCV>
            <PPIIMI>123</PPIIMI>
            <VER>10</VER>
            <INI>web</INI>
        </PMT>
        <PMT>
            <ID>AX</ID>
            <CCS>NONE</CCS>
            <ADS>false</ADS>
            <SCV>MAN</SCV>
        </PMT>
    </PCTX>");
    
    xdoc.Descendants("PMT").Where(x => x.Element("ID").Value == "AW")
        .SelectMany(c => c.Elements()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ADS" ||
                   e.Name.LocalName == "SCV"))
        .Remove();

    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
}
```

**Output**

```
<PCTX>
  <PMT>
    <ID>AW</ID>
    <CCS>NONE</CCS>
    <PPIIMI>123</PPIIMI>
    <VER>10</VER>
    <INI>web</INI>
  </PMT>
  <PMT>
    <ID>AX</ID>
    <CCS>NONE</CCS>
    <ADS>false</ADS>
    <SCV>MAN</SCV>
  </PMT>
</PCTX>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ([sandbox](https://onlinegdb.com/Z17S9WbYyY), i saw you used `XmlNode` and probably also `XmlDocument`, so I used it in my sample also):

```
// Select all PMT nodes with an ID node value of "AW"
XmlNodeList pmtNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//PMT[ID='AW']");

// Iterate through each selected PMT node
foreach (XmlNode pmtNode in pmtNodes)
{
    // Remove the ADS and SCV nodes from the current PMT node
    XmlNode adsNode = pmtNode.SelectSingleNode("ADS");
    XmlNode scvNode = pmtNode.SelectSingleNode("SCV");

    if (adsNode != null)
    {
        pmtNode.RemoveChild(adsNode);
    }

    if (scvNode != null)
    {
        pmtNode.RemoveChild(scvNode);
    }
}
```